# The excel report Settings pop-up doesn't show on getting an excel report

Tags: c#, reporting, stimulsoft

I use Stimulsoft 2017. Once I click on the excel report's option nothing appears, which was supposed to show export settings as it is shown below.And it just download the excel report all of a sudden.

[image]

I use this code to generate excel,but these settings don't make any effect on exported excel files.

```
    void StiReportViewer_ReportExport(object sender, StiExportDataEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Settings.GetExportFormat() == StiExportFormat.Excel || e.Settings.GetExportFormat() == StiExportFormat.Excel2007)
        {
           // this.StiReportViewer.ExportResponse = false;
            Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiExcelExportSettings stiExcelExportSettings = new Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiExcelExportSettings();
            stiExcelExportSettings.ExportDataOnly = true;
            stiExcelExportSettings.UseOnePageHeaderAndFooter = true;
            stiExcelExportSettings.ExportPageBreaks = false;
            stiExcelExportSettings.ExportObjectFormatting = false;
            MemoryStream xlsMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            e.Report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Excel, xlsMemoryStream, stiExcelExportSettings);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Report.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.BinaryWrite(xlsMemoryStream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I figure out that it runs with js, and there is a line of code that should change this way.

```
   <Sti:StiWebViewer ID="StiReportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" RenderMode="AjaxWithCache" 
                    ButtonsImagesPath="Images" ToolBarBackColor="WhiteSmoke" OnGetReportData="StiReportViewer_GetReportData" ButtonImagesPath="Images/ReportViewer/" ShowExportDialog="false">                    
                </Sti:StiWebViewer>
```

should change this way as show below:

```
 <Sti:StiWebViewer ID="StiReportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" RenderMode="AjaxWithCache" 
                    ButtonsImagesPath="Images" ToolBarBackColor="WhiteSmoke" OnGetReportData="StiReportViewer_GetReportData" ButtonImagesPath="Images/ReportViewer/" ShowExportDialog="true">                    
                </Sti:StiWebViewer>
```